# Switch Wifi On/Off in a toggle button Android

Tags: android, switch-statement, android-wifi, togglebutton

I know that to switch Wi-Fi state I have to do this:

```
wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
```

and write the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
```

I made two radio buttons (on/off) and they goes but it's not the best solution, so I want to create a toggle button. How can I put the code inside a toggle button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this in your Activity :

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private ToggleButton btn;
    private WifiManager wifiManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        wifiManager = (WifiManager)this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        btn = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_id);
        btn.setChecked(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled());

        btn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(isChecked);
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Check the [ToggleButton documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html).

Comment: This is a button right? Because i'm looking for a toggle solution

Comment: Nice nice thanks.. This example is only to enable the wifi? have i to make the same but instead of `btn.setChecked(enabled);` will be `btn.setChecked(disabled);` or not?

Comment: _isChecked_ will be set to true if the state is checked, false otherwise. See [CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener.html)

Comment: So this is all right? When toggle's check wifi starts and when toggle's off stops right?

Answer (score 0):

To actually toggle, meaning, switching the state, use:

```
WifiManager wm = ((WifiManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE));
wm.setWifiEnabled(!wm.isWifiEnabled());
```